# Acceptance testing page with multiple users

Tags: testing, integration-testing

I have a situation where I need to test multiple users accessing and updating a specific web page.  Its an auction page and I need to test up to three users bidding on the item, asserting that the browser shows the correct responses.

For example:

- user 1 logs in
- user 2 logs in
- user 3 logs in
- user 1 bids - is winning
- user 2 bids - is winning - user 1 is outbid and gets a notification
- user 3 bids but not enough
- user 3 bids again is winning - user 1 and user 2 get outbid notification

At the moment I have a set of scripts that perform these steps in sequence, logging each user in and out each time a bid is performed.I'm using PHP and Codeception with PhantomJS to do this but the tests are taking minutes to run.

I'm looking for advice on

1. the best approach to test this, and
2. tooling that can achieve testing the users in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first. UI testing *is* inherently slow. I don't think you can expect a dramatic increase in performance going down that path.

Sure, you can run your tests on a faster machine, with better internet connectivity, but that will only take you so far.

Having said that, one type of performance improvement is to run your UI tests in parallel. Meaning either in multiple browser instances on your machine (but again, there are physical limits on the resources of your machine) or in multiple nodes that a central orchestrator runs tests on (e.g. take a look at Selenium Grid).

On the other hand, the best approach to tackle this issue in my opinion, is to completely skip UI tests and move **all** the business logic you're trying to test in the server-side code tier.

That way, you can focus on writing tests that test your business logic - which I guess is what's most important (I hope your stakeholders share that view - this is key).

For more details on this approach, I recommend taking a look at this talk on [Clean Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsjsiz2A9mg). It's an hour long, but it's worth it!

Comment: I do indeed have integration and unit tests for the business logic.  What I need to test/simulate is a 'live' auction, and test the interface does what is expected.